# How did the Goa'uld Raiding team return in the beginning of the pilot?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

At the very beginning of SG1, the Goa'uld invade Earth, and then return somehow. How did they manage to return? There was no DHD, and somehow they didn't let it be known where they were going, IE, there was no log of the return. This seems a bit odd to me...

Comment: That's an excellent point/question.  Maybe one had the cell phone equivalent of a DHD?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's an excellent question, which was answered in the recently-released re-cut '[Children of the Gods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0029WLJHK)'.

As noted on the [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Gods):

> When Apophis and his Jaffa infiltrate Stargate Command, they are able
>   to leave without any apparent way of dialing or powering the gate. His
>   Jaffa dialed out manually. In the "Final Cut" version, Apophis can be
>   heard ordering a manual dial. This leaves the issue of where it got
>   the power, though it should be noted that the gate was still hooked
>   up.

Comment: "Recently re-cut" - It took them over a decade to notice and fix this, awesome.

Comment: @Keen: They also took out the nude scene.

Comment: *NOOOOOOOOOOOO!*

Comment: In the original version I don't think it was shown that the incoming wormhole ever closed. I think they retreated through the incoming wormhole, which of course shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Xantec Well, a lot of those early episodes had some sort of inconsistency due to the rules not being nailed down yet.

Comment: @Izkata Not being able to go through an incoming wormhole was established in the movie

Comment: @Xantec It looks like they had nailed down the rule, that was the problem. See the commentary quote below. They also poke fun at the issue in the 200th episode.

Comment: Link is broken ATM

Comment: @FrankerZ - which link?  They seem to be working for me.

Comment: @Jeff Looks like rads.stackoverflow.com might have been down for a bit yesterday. I was getting server errors when attemping to click your first link.

Answer (score 16):

### Short answer - It's a mistake by the writer

In the commentary for the "final cut" version, Brad Wright and Richard Dean Anderson specifically mention that in the original [script](http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Stargate-SG1-Children-Of-The-Gods.html) Jonathan Glassner (co-creator of Stargate) wrote the scene in such a way that it broke one of the fundamental rules of the Stargate universe, i.e that gate travel is uni-directional. The implication is clearly that Apophis dialled in, then left via **another** dialled in wormhole.

> **Brad Wright:** *The reason we had to put that other shot in, was
>   because the way Jonathan originally wrote this opening scene, was uh,
>   broke the rules of Stargate…*
>
> **RDA:** *Uh?*
>
> **BW:** *…so that little moment where…*
>
> **RDA:** *Which were?*
>
> **BW:** *...well, you can't go through a puddle and then step back through it. They had to stop and redial somehow.*
>
> **RDA:** *Oh! That's true.*

In the ***original*** episode "Children of the God", we see Apophis and his Jaffa enter the facility at [2:26](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0X66RDi86w). A brief firefight ensues and we see the gate has closed at around [4:09](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0X66RDi86w).

[image: Stargate Children of the Gods]

Apohphis then tilts his head at the gate and [tells his Jaffa](http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Stargate-SG1-Children-Of-The-Gods.html) "**K'on! A'nsi**" in Goa'uld. Although there's no literal translation offered in either the episode or the script, I think we can reasonably assume that this is something along the lines of "take up defensive positions"

At around [4:40](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0X66RDi86w) (some 20 seconds of realtime later but an undefined amount of film time later), we rejoin the action in the gateroom where we see that another wormhole has been connected.

In the "Final Cut" version, the episode order is clearer. After the firefight, Apophis turns to his Jaffa and orders them to "Kala Chappa-ai" ("dial the gate")

Although it's not made clear how they do it, there's a couple of possibilities;

- Teal'c could have used the same device that was later retconned into the film continuum which basically attached directly to the gate and allowed a manual dial, described as a [portable DHD](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Dial_Home_Device)

[image: Portable DHD]

- The Jaffa had a power source powerful enough to power the gate, perhaps by using Liquid naquadah (e.g. from a staff weapon) or simply by diverting one of the electrical conduits on the wall and then moving the bezel around manually like Teal'c did in "[Prisoners](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Prisoners)"

Comment: I just rewatched the episode and feel there's simply not enough time for the last possibility. The retconned portable DHD *could* work if they don't have to leave it behind. I'd have to watch the movie again to see whether that indeed works, but it seems the logical way to fix their original mistake.

Comment: @Mast - I don't think that wrenching a power cable off the wall and literally shoving it into the side of the gate would take as much time as you think, especially if you know the address you want to go to and make sure it's one that can be dialled quickly :-)

Comment: Hooking up the cable isn't the problem, it's manually rotating the heavy ring that takes a while.

Comment: @Mast - Did you not notice the room filled with burly men who appear to spend most of the time oiling themselves, taking steroids and flexing? I reckon they could turn the ring quite easily.

Comment: @Valorum I'd argue that rotating the gate's inner ring would be tricky if you're oiled up :D

Answer (score 2):

It's been suggested that Apophis had a wireless hand-dial device that we saw elsewhere, I believe with the Nox. That would also explain how they didn't get vaporized by the ka-woosh when the gate re-activated.

Comment: The Nox don't have a device - they dial it using their psychic powers.  In the episode 1969, however, we see a future version of Cassandra use a handheld dialing device.

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure whether this is canon, but http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Amplifier_bracelet