# How does Apophis reopen the Stargate in the opening scene of the pilot?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How did the Goa’uld Raiding team return in the beginning of the pilot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/how-did-the-goauld-raiding-team-return-in-the-beginning-of-the-pilot)

In the first sequence of the *SG-1* pilot, *Children of Gods*, Apophis and some Jaffa come to Earth, fight a bit, kidnap a human and leave through the Stargate. (Standard Goa'uld procedure, Apophis read the manual correctly!)

My question is: how do they go back through the Gate? They can't activate it from Earth for a whole bunch of reasons!

- The Earth gate has no DHD but a computer. Jaffas can't manipulate computers.
- The Tauri tried every combinations but only found Abydos as a destination. The computer must be re-calibrated first (as explained later in the episode). Even if they could use a computer, the only destination would have been Abydos, but no one came through the gate on that planet.
- The Stargate is one-way only, it can't be opened from the other side.
- Goa'ulds don't have the knowledge to open Stargates at will like Asgards do.

Am I missing something or was that scene totally wrong?

Answer (score 5):

It's probably just bad writing.

Otherwise I'm having only two major issues with the whole plot:

- How did they dial home? As you mentioned there's no DHD and the whole gate is "rigged", i.e. even some kind of mobile device wouldn't work necessarily.
- Even more important: They obviously abducted women from slave worlds. How did they know the Earth gate is functional once again? Is this the first time in 3000+ years they tried again? Did they try all former gates (assuming more gates were blocked)?

I don't have any issues regarding updated addresses and such, as this is mainly an Earth issue to me: The system lords never stopped using the gates, so they probably kept their stuff up-to-date.

Comment: From memory, I think Apphis manipulated some controls on his wrist or gauntlet to dial the gate. At the time I just assumed they must have such technology, after all at that point I don't think we've even been shown a DHD. Ra's warriors in the film use controls on their wrists or finger rings to activate the transport rings, so similar controls for the gate seemed to make sense. Not necessarily a mistake at the time, maybe that's how dialling was supposed to work and later the writers/producers changed their minds.

Comment: @SimonHibbs - We are introduced to the DHD a few minutes later, when Carter first sees it. "This is what was missing from the dig in Giza. [snip] Look how small it is!" But you're right I think the writers just forgot about the arm mounted diallers. As for figuring out whether Earth Gate was open - remember Ra had just been taken out, and Apophis (his mortal enemy) claimed his territory his own. It's possible that Ra "covered up" the uprising of Earth, and it was just 'good timing' on Apophis' part to check out his new dominion.

Comment: There are also the miniature devices the Nox have been seen using and even Casandra in the 1960s episode when SG1 was thrown forward in time to far... But I agree with plot holes... just like in the original movie we just happened to have a setup for the MALP to track itself across the galaxy when we didn't even know what was happening?! Though I guess that could have just been a really good guess from someone who knew about the Earnest Littefield incident...

Comment: Other issue with them dialing back out is they were standing the on splash zone for the event horizon.  So Apothos should be dead.

Comment: Well, at least they have used orb to observe site on other side. So they have known that there are no DHD on other side. Seems reasonable for Apophis to have portable DHD, as artifact, that don't have to mean that this is common technology for goa'uld, just old ancient artifact. And this can counteract coordinates shift. But yes, manual dialing would be off limit, thatnks to coordinate shift, and gate wasn't able to receive update from DHD.