# In Star-Gate SG-1, ep.1, how did the invaders dial out?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the first episode of SG-1, the base is attacked by aliens. After they arrive, the gate closes. How were they able to dial out again? They apparently did not access the control room.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How did the Goa'uld Raiding team return in the beginning of the pilot?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/how-did-the-goauld-raiding-team-return-in-the-beginning-of-the-pilot)

Comment: Simon's comment covers it. Thanks!
https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11466/how-did-the-goauld-raiding-team-return-in-the-beginning-of-the-pilot